# Disable full wipe capability in android

Tags: android, mdm

How can we disable full wipe capability of the device to prevent full wipe from occurring in any instance?

Is it possible that we can prevent a device from getting wiped? If yes, how?

I have looked into the device admin api but there i can see only wipe api for the device which wipes the device data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you'll be able to disable this functionality without rooting the phone and installing a custom ROM. Both [HTCSense.com](http://htcsense.com) and the [Device Policy Admin](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1056433) app use it. These are provided by HTC and Google respectively.

It's unlikely that either HTC or Google would let an app disable core features that their services rely upon.